# I want to display parts of the form according to the how the user selects the checkbox

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

How do i allow to display a particular form content after the user clicks on checkbox Yes or No
for e.g.if the user clicks on yes checkbox display the form to be filled if user clicks No display another form part to be filled
I want to add it here like in my applyonline.html

```
{% extends "pmmvyapp/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load static %}
{% block content%}
<div class="col-md-8">
<form method="post" action="/add_aganwadi/">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group">
      <div class=" mb-4">
      <h6><u>Please Fill up the details below (Note that all the fields are required)</u></h6>
    </div>
    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4" ,align="center">Beneficiary Details</legend>
    <label for="formGropuNameInput">Does Beneficiary have a Driving License Card?*</label>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        {% if..... %}
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">Yes</label>

        {% else %}
        </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="option2">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox2">No</label>
            </div>
        </div> 
      {% endif %}
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-bottom:10px ">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>   
{% endblock %}
```

I want to know if I can use the if statement to achieve this and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't have any problem in including angularjs in form page and radio button instead of check box this below sample code image i used previously will help you[image]

Comment: How can I do it for 3 checkboxes?

Comment: if it is for checkbox then you have use functions concept which is little bit lengthy